# Autorotating on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, rotation, uilabel

In a few of my `UIView`s, I have a few `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s. They are in a good position when the `UIView` is in portrait mode, but the positioning on the `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s are messed up when the `UIView` becomes landscape mode.

How can I make sure that the `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s are in the correct place for both portrait and landscape mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `autoresizingMask` properly, this will solve your problem automatically.

Comment: I have tried using `self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;` but doesn't seem to be working. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do.Just Apply Transform to convert their x,y coordinate from landscape to portrait ,etc.

Comment: Kindly Provide me your sample code.So,that i can tell you in detail